# Facebook API - Authentication similar to Hootsuite

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to implement a system to retrieve information from a user of facebook independently of the user being logged into facebook.

I have user access token in my database but every time the user needs to login on facebook.

My question is how the authentication of Hootsuite (hootsuite.com) works because there it is not necessary.Just logging in the Hootsuite is possible to recover all data from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about (If I understand you correctly) is a breech of privacy in the eyes of Facebook.  A user has to be interacting with an application in order for it to retrieve information about the user.

Facebook's API access works by means of an `access_token` that is specific to the user and the application that requested it.  `access_token`'s have a limited time frame that they are valid, after that the application would have to request a new one or request an extension on that token.  In either case, the user would have to be interacting with the application, and therefore logged into Facebook, when such a request is made.

I'm unfamiliar with the website you referred to but it is not in the scope of this site to reverse engineer some one else's application.

Comment: Hootsuite is just a example. I believe if they do that the facebook api allows that action. In my case I must allow a user link many facebook profiles with a user of my application. This is feasible?

Comment: Whether or not it's feasible for **you** I can't say - but it **is** possible... Its just like giving a user two different passwords...